# How do dependency grammars account for information structure

Tags: syntax, dependency-grammar, information-structure

In phrase structure grammars, discourse functions (topic, focus) have structural positions (cf. topicalization in English, right-edge focus in Russian, clause-initial focus in Welsh, preverbal focus in Hungarian). What do dependency grammars employ to capture information structure? There are no nonterminals so one can't have an FP, for example, or a TopP.

Answer (score 1):

One can't account for information structure at the level of surface syntax. Consider the sentence **илсьірбоит** (I'm showing it to her; Abkhaz). It has three topical arguments (only topics can be pro-dropped) and since a sentence without focus wouldn't be felicitous, the predicate is focal. But the syntax tree consists of only one node. It's useless. The LFG people suggest to ignore the categorial structure and introduce discourse functions into the functional structure. But it was Tracy Holloway King I think who pointed out that this approach doesn't work for subconstituent focus. It's easy to see that any dependency grammar would have this problem. The solution within LFG was to add a new layer of representation for discourse functions to the theory.

In FGD Sgall et al. reorder their tectogrammatical trees with respect to information structure. But at the same time they require that the trees be projective. I don't think that their solution is particularly elegant but if they weren't able to come up with a nice solution, then there's probably none within the framework.

One possible "solution" is to say that information structure isn't part of syntax sensu stricto and capture it at the level of pragmatics. This is what Jerry Hobbs did in his framework and it makes sense, but it also moves us from linguistics to computational logic and/or automated reasoning.

Comment: I don't think what's dropped in your Russian example qualify as topics. The dropped pronouns are old information, and old information and topics do not necessarily overlap. Consider in this regard that according to your reasoning, clauses would often contain more than one topic. In other words, your analysis is claiming that in a sentence such as "He gave her it", three topics are present: "He", "her", and "it". Is that right?

Comment: "One can't account for information structure at the level of surface syntax." I disagree. Topological theories (Duchier and Debusmann,
Gerdes and Kahane) actually work very well.

Comment: @TimOsborne It's Abkhaz and it's topic because Abkhaz has a rule that pro-dropped arguments are always topical. It's language specific. Old information can be focal it it's contrastive. BTW clauses often contain more than one topical phrase/argument. The terminology usually is that sentences are divided into topic and focus and in the example above the topic would consist of three nominal arguments.

Comment: @ThomasGross It may work in some languages, but in a polysynthetic language like Abkhaz one gets into difficulties (in Debusmanns theory the topological tree would have only one node, right?). I'm not familiar with MTT so maybe someone from that camp could comment on the example.

Comment: Your use of terminology is debatable.  You are using the term "topical" to mean old information. Sentences have one topic; my linguistics dictionaries agree about that. Crystal writes: "The topic of a sentence is the entity (person, thing, etc.) about which somehting is said, whereas the further statement made about this entity is the comment." Note that he does not write "...the entities about which...".

Comment: @TimOsborne So he's wrong. In a sentence like "devuška čitaet knigu" (girl-nom reads book-acc; I'm giving a Russian example because I don't want articles to complicate the interpretation) every word can be either topical or focal. The only constraint is that at least one word has to be focal. It's obvious that both the subject and object can be part of the topic, right? See Sgall, Kruijff, King, Butt, Kiss, Hobbs..., in fact everybody who did serious research on information structure.

Comment: We're working with varying notions of "topic". Interestingly, you do not write that sentences have more than one topic, but rather you consistently reach to the term "topical". You might endorse the following statement: "A clause can have more than one topic.". Do you endorse this statement? Note that the notions of topic-comment, theme-rheme, and old-new information, all overlap. When I read about these notions, I quickly see that they are not clear-cut. They are not as black and white as you seem to suggest.

Comment: @TimOsborne I use the terminology of King and Sgall: a sentence has one topic (if it has one) which can consist of more than one constituents or phrases. A phrase it topical if it's part of the topic of the sentence. I'm using a precise definition but there are too many definitions of topic/focus which leads to confusion. To rephrase what you wrote: A clause can have more than one topical phrases. But I have no problem with a different terminology.  Matthews, BTW, distinguishes between sentence and discours topics. Another source of confusion...

Comment: @Atamiri Surface syntax begins with two nodes. In surface syntactic accounts, polysynthetic languages force one to grant morphological material node status. I'm not familiar with Abkhaz (and I wish you had chosen a language with more accessible on-line information), so I can't comment.

Comment: @ThomasGross OK, so the tree for the one (polysynthetic) word would have four nodes. It makes sense but what if all arguments were overt? Would the tree have 7 nodes? There'd be two subjects, two direct objects, and two indirect objects. Another language with the same "problem" is Quechua. Or Greenlandic, if that helps.

Comment: @ThomasGross BTW the Polish sentence "pada" (it's raining) has only one node, there are no arguments.

Comment: @Atamiri The appearance of overt arguments together with their corresponding markers inside the verb isn't really a problem. Very similar data are known from clitic doubling, and from syntactic doubling. Of course, in your example there would be only **one** subject, direct object, and indirect object each. There would be seven nodes, though, of which four would be projecting (subject, DO, IO, and V).

Comment: @Atamiri re "pada". If there's nothing else, then there's no syntax here, just a word. It's an utterance for sure. This is not really worth discussing: if there's only one entity, no relationship can be discerned. This is a classic since Plato.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of answers to this question, depending upon whether a multistratal syntax (deep syntax and surface syntax) or monostratal syntax (surface syntax only) is assumed.

In monostratal syntax, information structure is encoded by linear order alone. This is the same for both grammar types, dependency and constituency. For instance, a topic can be construed as the constituent that appears at the left edge of an utterance.

Note that I have used the term "constituent" to describe the syntactic unit at the left edge of the utterance in a dependency grammar. For example:

```
 (1)   a. You still have much to learn.

       b. Much to learn you still have.
```

In a dependency grammar, complete subtrees are constituents. In both (1a) and (1b), the string *much to learn* is a constituent, i.e. a complete subtree. In (1b) it can be labeled the "topic". As a constituent, it has a concrete status in the dependency hierarchy. The following trees (taken from the article on [topicalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topicalization) in Wikipedia) illustrate this state of affairs in both a constituency and a dependency grammar:

[image]

These trees illustrate the extent to which notions such as topic and focus are going to receive the same sort of explanation in both dependency- and constituency-based systems. These notions are taken care of by linear order alone, and the distinction between dependency and constituency has no bearing on topics and foci.

On a multistratal approach, however, things become more complex, since dependency grammars that posit deep syntax also acknowledge information structure in deep syntax. The main dependency grammars that do this are Meaning-Text Theory (MTT) and Functional Generative Description (FGD). However,these DGs can nevertheless also assume that constituents (complete subtrees) are marked in deep syntax as topic or focus. In the mapping that occurs fron deep syntax to surface structure, a topic should then appear at the left periphery of the utterance.

Now if the question is more concerned with how notions of FocP and TopP in Chomskian syntax translate to dependency grammar, that question is perhaps more difficult to anwer in a coherent manner. The difficulty stems from the fact that modern Chomskian syntax assumes all syntactic branching to be binary. This can lead to a large number of various functional categories, all located above the lexical domain in the syntactic hierarchy. What one has to ask oneself, though, is whether these functional categories can exist without linear order. That is, one has to ask oneself whether one can have a topic that does not appear at the left edge of the utterance. If no such topics are possible, the notion of topic cannot be separated from linear order, so there is no reason to locate the notion of topic in the syntactic hierarchy. But if one can have a topic that is not at the left periphery of the utterance, then one has to ask oneself what the Chomskian syntax tree would look like that acknowledges such a topic. For instance, can a topic follow the finite verb? I think many syntacticians would answer this question with "no".

Comment: "information structure is encoded by linear order" That wouldn't work for languages that signal information structure morphologically. "constituents (complete subtrees) are marked in deep syntax as topic or focus" The information-structural status of a head might differ from that of its children.

Comment: OK, but it wouldn't need to mark it with linear order, because it marks it morphologically. The redundancy would be unnecessary. But the issue is not so clear. I'm thinking of the topic marker "-wa" in Japanese. The extent to which "-wa" actually marks a topic is debatable.

Comment: "For instance, can a topic follow the finite verb? I think many syntacticians would answer this question with "no"." Yes, it can, in many languages.

Comment: For instance? Examples? And are these topics marked morphologically?

Comment: Focalization in Welsh is a nice (configurational) example. Or (anti)topics in French. But it's possible in most (if not all) free word order languages. I don't think there's one syntactician who'd seriously believe that there's a language that doesn't allow for topics following verbs.

Comment: The languages that I know and study, all encode topics in terms of word order, In German, topics immediately precede the finite verb, In English, non-subject topics immediately precede the subject (which precedes the finite verb), In Chinese, non-subject topics also generally precede the subject (which precedes the verb). How about an example from French of a topic that is following the verb? I need to know what such a topic looks like.

Comment: In "ihn habe ich gesehen" "him" can be focal. Even in English such a sentence is possible. And even if it weren't, there are some 6,000 languages in the world. One can always find a counterexample. As for French, google it up (my French is too rusted but the structure is: pro(s) verb topic-NP*, that is, focus come first). There are also examples from Russian (in King: Configuring topic and focus).

Comment: Our disagreement revolves around how "topic" and "focus" are defined. My linguistics dictionaries (Trask, Crystal, Matthews) are not entirely clear about this. Most examples have the topic at the left-periphery, although some examples are given in which a topic appears further to the right. So my last statement in my answer was not accurate. Conceded. But I won't concede is that sentence can have multiple topics. I find no evidence for that in my linguistics dictionaries. Furthermore, your use of the terms "fopical" and "focal" is rather loose.

Comment: My understanding of topic-focus articulation follows that of Sgall (who in turn agrees with King, Kiss, and many others). I agree that there are different approaches to information structure and some researchers use the terms differently. Maybe it's better to say presupposition and proffered content (as in pragmatics). In any case, when I say, for example, "the orange duck went to his office", it can be just the office what's focal. Or just the duck. Or just its orangeness. The presupposition is defined as what can be inferred from the preceding discourse, which is topic for Sgall et al.

Answer (score -3):

Chomsky proposed that linguistics should be explanatory rather than taxonomic, and mostly, modern linguists have agreed with him.  Taxonomic linguistics endeavors to develop a framework of terminology that is sufficient to describe facts of natural language, as we encounter them.  This is the sort of thing that preoccupied linguists in the midst of the 20th century, and led to, e.g., tagmemics, or stratificational grammar.

Under Chomsky's influence, we don't do that anymore.  It appears to me, you are asking a taxonomical question.  Not wishing to sound mean, but my answer is: Who cares?